# Парсинг bash.im

Tags: регулярные-выражения, c++, синтаксический-анализ

Хочется получить все цитаты с данной страницы [bash.im](http://bash.im) в массиве. Нужна регулярка, которая это сделает. Пока только начинаю их изучать, поэтому самому сложно ее написать.
И еще. Какая библиотека лучшая для работы с регулярками в С++? Они же не поддерживаются языком со стандартными библиотеками?
Спасибо!

Comment: Возьмите [любой `HTML` парсер][1] и выцепите контент всех элементов `.quote .text` (если вам не нужна мета-информация по каждой цитате).

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489522/library-recommendation-c-html-parser

Comment: Да что ж вас всех тянет тянет парсить HTML регулярными выражениями[?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/276994)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Использовать C++ для обдирания веб-страниц нецелесообразно, поскольку основные потери в скорости при работе с вебом приходятся на ввод/вывод, а не на вычисления, а трудоемкость кодирования на C++ выше, чем на PHP/Python/Ruby.
2. Использовать регулярные выражения для анализа HTML нецелесообразно, потому что HTML может быть невалидным и то выражение, которое подходит для одного документа, не подойдет для другого.

Тем не менее, регулярное выражение для этого цитатника может выглядеть так:

```
<div class="text">(.*)<\/div>
```

В C++ можно уверенно работать с [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html).

P.S. Для C++ разумно использовать связку: libcurl (выкачивание), libtidy (нормализация), libxml (XPath выражения на извлечение текста).

Comment: спасибо за советы!

Comment: регулярными выражениями нельзя корректно парсить грамматики второго типа по Хомскому.

Comment: как мило))